# issue creating new java fx Projects

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Im having issues creating a new javafx project, when i create it it gives flags off the bat saying that some of the imports aren't resolved to a type and i don't know what causing it. Ive installed e(fx)clipse which i thought was supposed to fix and import all the libraries needed to run javafx. [image]

im using java-SE13 which to my understanding could run JavaFX

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: i tried that and it gave me another error 
Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Comment: no screenshots of text, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely did not download the JavaFX library and link it. JavaSE13 **cannot** run javaFX on its own, the javaFX library is a separate library that must be additionally downloaded from openjfx.io and linked to your program.

Comment: how do i go about as to linking it?

Comment: Assuming your using eclipse like in your screenshot:

1. Right click your project

2. At the very bottom click properties

3. Click on the option "Java Build Path" from the left side list of options

4. Navigate to the "Libraries" Tab

5. Choose Add Library (this library would be a modulepath library)

6. Select 'User Library', then press 'Next'

7. Click  'User Libraries...'

8. Choose 'Import'

9. Add file path to javaFX 14